# Prove that a parametrization is a injective function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, parametrization

I have the following problem:

> Let $\textbf{x}$: $(-\pi,\pi)\times(-\pi,\pi)\rightarrow R^3$ such
> that
>
> $$\textbf{x}(\theta,t)=((2+\cos(t))\cos(\theta),(2+\cos(t))\sin(\theta),\sin(t))$$

I want to prove that $\textbf{x}$ is a injective function. I tried by the definition of injective function, but I didn't get it. That problem are in the frame of differential geometry

My attemp:

Let  $(\theta_{1},t_{1}),(\theta_{2},t_{2})\in (-\pi,\pi)$ such that $\textbf{x}(\theta_{1},t_{1})=\textbf{x}(\theta_{2},t_{2})$.
Then

1. $$(2+\cos(t_{1}))\cos(\theta_{1})=(2+\cos(t_{2}))\cos(\theta_{2})$$
2. $$(2+\cos(t_{1}))\sin(\theta_{1})=(2+\cos(t_{2}))\sin(\theta_{2})$$
3. $$\sin(t_{1})=\sin(t_{2})$$

We can say, from the last equality:

$t_{1} = \pi - t_{2}$ , if $t_{1},t_{2}\geq 0$

$t_{1} = -\pi - t_{2}$ , if $t_{1},t_{2}\leq 0$

$t_{1}=t_{2}$

We want to prove that if any of the first two happens, then (1) or (2) is not true.

Comment: To be honest that seems to be just a direct checking.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you have your system of equations. You can create a new one by using $(1)^2+(2)^2 $, which yields :

$$(2+cos(t_1))^2=(2+cos(t_2))^2 $$
And since everything is positive, you have :
$$cos(t_1)=cos(t_2), sin(t1)=sin(t_2), (3) $$
So you have $t_1=t_2$, then, you can plug it in the first 2 equations and simplify by $(2+cos(t_{1,2}))$ (since they are the same), and you also get :
$$sin(\theta_1)=sin(\theta_2), cos(\theta_1)=cos(\theta_2) $$
Then you can conclude that :

$$x(t_1,\theta_1)=x(t_2,\theta_2) \Rightarrow (t_1,\theta_1)=(t_2,\theta_2)$$

So your function is injective

Comment: Thank you so much bro!!!